# SVG remove text above/below padding

Tags: css, svg, text

I am trying to remove above/below padding from SVG text element.

Here how is now:

[image: Pic of TEXT with padding]!

How I want to be:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIA9E.png]

This is the SVG code

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" style="margin-top: 100px;" viewBox="0 0 1656 614" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <g id="mySVG"> 
    <text x="0" y="0" dx="0" dy="0" fill="#000"  style="font-family: DINPro; font-size: 120px;" dominant-baseline="hanging" class="text-0">TEEEEEEXT</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see from the picture link, there's padding above and below only.

If anyone can help me how to remove this padding I'll be thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: adjust the viewbox

Answer (score 1):

Remove the style attribute from the svg (to remove the top "padding" - although it is margin) and reduce the last digit in the viewBox attribute to remove the bottom "padding" (although that is the height of the svg) - below I have reduced the height from 614 to 120 (the size of your font).

If you want the font to be larger, you may need to also reduce the width from 1656 (as the svg is set to preserve it's aspect ratio)

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1656 120" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <g id="mySVG"> 
    <text x="0" y="0" dx="0" dy="0" fill="#000"  style="font-family: DINPro; font-size: 120px;" dominant-baseline="hanging" class="text-0">TEEEEEEXT</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I can't reduce the height of the SVG because I need an image background with fixed size. So how can I reduce the bottom padding. Thank you.

Comment: If you're not willing to reduce the height then it will always have bottom "padding" unless you make the font size the same size as the height

Answer (score 1):

The "padding" is part of the font. It is space reserved for characters that extend above the height of an uppercase letter or below the baseline. You can't remove it.  It will always be included in the `<text>` element's bounding box.